# Partial order relation

Tags: logic, notation, definition, relations, order-theory

> Define the relation $\leq$ on a boolean algebra $B$ by 
>   for all $x,y\in B$, $x\leq y \iff x\lor y=y$, show that $\leq$ is a partial order relation.

First of all what exactly does boolean algebra $B$ look like? can you give me an example of a set $A$ that is a boolean algebra???

I have done alot of examples to prove equivalence relation last week and the idea is straight forward and with this one I first tried to prove reflexivity antisymmetry and transitive

Reflexivity:
for any element $x$ that is in $B$, $x\leq x$ that is $x\lor x=x$?? This part doesnt make sense to me nor do I know what does $x\lor x$ mean, $x$ or $x$ as a set operation 'OR' if so could you guys lead me in a bit

I think once I understand what exactly $x\lor y=y$ means and how I can manupulate it I think I will be ok to prove antisymmetry transitivity and reflexivity.

Comment: Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)#Definition).

Comment: Where did you find this problem? If this is a homework assignment, or an exercise from a book, you should find in the relevant notes/chapter the definition of a Boolean algebra and some discussion on this structure. If there is none, contact your teacher or the author of the book and request clarifications while searching for "Boolean algebra definition" on Google.

Comment: Its an assignment problem  and i have donw almost all the reading i could i am a distance student so communication is a little hard but i seem to just find this question particularly hard. what i don't get now after spending so much time is how to manipulate say transitivity which i would imagine would be like if xVy=y and yVz=z then xVz=z ????? is that right and then use may be set rules to manipulate the first two equations to look like the third?

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to read this answer, please have a look at some [equivalent definitions of a Boolean algebra](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aBoolean_Algebra).

The canonical example of a Boolean algebra $(B,\lor,\land,\neg)$ is the power set of a set: $(\mathcal P(S), \cup,\cap,\complement)$ where $\complement$ denotes the complement operation $\complement(S') = \{s \in S: s \notin S'\}$.

Note that for $\le$ to be a partial order, it should be reflexive, transitive and *antisymmetric*: $x\le y$ and $y \le x$ imply $x = y$. A partial order is **not** the same as an equivalence relation (which replaces antisymmetry with symmetry).

---

A proof that $x \lor x = x$ is given [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Operations_of_Boolean_Algebra_are_Idempotent).

What may have been given as an axiom for BAs to you is that [$\lor$ is associative](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Operations_of_Boolean_Algebra_are_Associative). Then, if $x \le y$ and $y \le z$, we have:
$$x \lor z = x \lor (y \lor z) = (x \lor y) \lor z = y \lor z = z$$
hence $x \le z$.

Finally, if $x \le y$ and $y \le z$, we have $y = x \lor y = y \lor x = x$.

Hence $\le$ is reflexive, transitive, and antisymmetric: a partial ordering.